# Is it possible to track how much of a certain channel you've watched on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that allows you to see what percent of your watch time was spent on a certain channel. Is there anyway collecting this data is possible from a user through a browser extension?

What I'm trying to do: If I spent 20 hours on Youtube and I spent 5 of the hours on let's say "Daily Dose of Internet", I would want to get back 25% of my watch time was spent on "Daily Dose of Internet".

What I've done so far: This is my first project doing something like this so I don't really know where to begin. I combed through most of Youtube's API for javascript but couldn't find anything.

Comment: How you define: `your watch time`? - I'm affraid you need to provide more information about what have you tried, what is your logic and the desired results = sample data.